# python: sendmail program works, if defined as functions it fails

Tags: python, function, header, sendmail

I have a RHEL box with python 2.4.3 and I'm trying to write a python script to send an email.

The problem I have is that the program itself works but when I define the code as function and I call the function, it complaints. How can I fix the function?

Actual error:

No recipient addresses found in header

This is code:

```
def send_mail():
   SENDMAIL = "/usr/sbin/sendmail" # sendmail location
   FROM = "sender@domain.ca"
   TO = ["recipient@domain.ca"]
   SUBJECT = "Any subject"
   TEXT = "Any Text."

   # Prepare actual message

   message = """\
   From: %s
   To: %s
   Subject: %s

   %s
   """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

   # Send the mail

   p = os.popen("%s -t -i" % SENDMAIL, "w")
   p.write(message)
   status = p.close()
   if status:
      print "Sendmail exit status", status

send_mail()
```

Thanks
Note: code taken from here: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-send-mail-from-a-python-script.htm

Comment: Why are you using `sendmail` instead of using a Python library?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python libraries. What library should I use? (for python 2.4.3)

Comment: Use `smtplib` https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Comment: Do you know if smtplib supports the use of a relay server? the sendmail approach works since it uses the OS configuration but I think smtplib expects to find a local smtp server

Comment: Yes it does. The first argument to `smtplib.SMTP()` is the name of the relay server.

Comment: I have a really simple script using smtplib but it fails with 'Connection Refused'. The line that fails is  `server = smtplib.SMTP('myrelayserver')`

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the port, I'm not sure, I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

The message shouldn't be indented. Header lines have to be at the beginning of the line; indentation in headers is used to indicate continuation of the previous header.

```
   message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and sends the email but control is never returned and the process that owns the program needs to be killed.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why that would behave differently when it's in a function than when you have the code at top level.